# get the pixel width of an element and convert to number

Tags: jquery, pixel

How to get the width of an element. Convert it to percentages (%). An reset the element width +1. I like the jplayer volume be also controlled by the mouse weel.
Problem is to get the pixel width as a number(integer).

.jp-volume-bar-value sets it width in %, but jquery get it in px and so must be converted to % (ratio 1.66).

To use parseInt on var loud does't seem to work (is get an different number).
Who can help?

```
      $('#volume-hold').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
        var loud =  $('.jp-volume-bar-value').css('width');
        var load = loud * 1.666666; //max px / 100
        var dir = delta > 0 ? 'Up' : 'Down',
            vel = Math.abs(delta);
        if (dir === 'Up') {
             var loud = loud + 1;
             $('.jp-volume-bar-value').css('width', '('+loud+')');
        }else{

        }            
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: parseInt should definitely work.

Comment: also when you're setting width again it should be $('.jp-volume-bar-value').css('width', loud+'px');
And you can get the width using parseInt($('.jp-volume-bar-value').width())

Comment: @AR thank you, gone ty it. Maybe I was thinking to difficult....

Comment: It works half, css width must be set in %, becous jplayer reads actual volume from % not from px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that `parseInt` isn't working because you're not setting the base. try:

```
var result = parseInt(loud * 1.666, 10); //sets parseInt to base 10
```

Also, you may want to ensure that the value you're getting back from jQuery is a number:

```
var width = Number($('#element').css('width'));
```

then you can try to `parseInt` it

Comment: I have a feeling the OP set the width using percent, but is getting pixel back, so therefore it's not "right". I'm guessing though. See http://jsfiddle.net/LKscV/

Comment: yeah you are probably right. OP didn't really give too many specifics, so my first instinct was typical `parseInt` base error